# Remove special quotation marks and other characters

Tags: python, nltk, python-newspaper

I am trying to download articles using `Article` from `newspaper`, and trying to tokenize the words using `nltk` `word_tokenizer`. The problem is, when I try to print the parsed article text, some of these articles have special quotation marks like `“`, `”`, `’`, which aren't filtered out by the tokenizer, as it would a regular `'` and `"`.

Is there a way to replace these special quotes with normal quotes, or better yet remove all possible speical characters that the tokenizer may miss out on?

I tried to remove these special characters by explicitly mentioning them in code, but it gives me the error `Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x92'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/) package would normally replace these characters with utf-8 ones.

```
from unidecode import unidecode
text = unidecode(text)
```

A drawback, however, is that you would also change some characters (e.g. accentuated ones) which you may want to keep. If that is the case, an option is to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to specifically erase (or replace) some pre-identified special characters:

```
import re
exotic_quotes = ['\\x92'] # fill this up
text = re.sub(exotic_quotes, "'", text) # changing the second argument to fill the kind of quote you want to replace the exotic ones with
```

I hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. Is there any way to completely remove any words with these non utf-8 characters? Because for my specific application, I don't really need any special characters, or punctuation, just the actual utf-8 words from the article.

Comment: You're very welcome. Using `unidecode` should replace all non utf-8 characters, but keep punctuation signs, etc.. If you want to keep letters (and whitespaces) only, use a regular expression : `text = re.sub('[^A-Za-z ]', '', text)`. And if you want to get rid of words containing any non-utf8 character, use more complex regular expressions !